# bash function with an export variable

Tags: bash

What is this bash function doing?

I guess it's defining a variable, and exporting it out of the shell.. somewhere. working memory?
and then what is the mate() function actually doing?

```
export TEXTMATE_PATH=/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate
mate () {
    $TEXTMATE_PATH $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6
}
```

I'm really new at this

Comment: It's simply a function definition.  A function that would invoke the said executable with 6 parameters passed to it.

Comment: By the way this is a bad definition: it will break with arguments that contain spaces. Go complain to the person who wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function pass the first six of its arguments to the program stored in the environment variable (`/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate`).

`export` is used to define an environment variable in the current shell (that is propagated in subshells, functions, and other subprocess).

Comment: Not all, just the first six, and breaking any quoting. The proper way to pass on command line arguments is `"$@"`.